# Block a site in webview

Tags: android, webview

In my apps webview i want to block some sites that users should not enter. For example how can i block all google sites (.com .fr etc.) without using

```
url.contains("google");
```

because some urls contain the word google but they dont browse to the site. For example: https://www.bing.com/search?q=google

Here is my code

```
web.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){

                @Override
                public void onPageStarted(WebView webView, String webUrl, Bitmap favicon) {


                    if(webUrl.contains("google")){//not works good
                        //block
                    }

                     super.onPageStarted(webView, webUrl, favicon);

                }



        });
```

Comment: Why did you delete your answer, then accept one that used the same code?

Comment: I can see the deleted answers... Now the one you accepted is deleted and you've answered your own question, but not accepted

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds simple but it could be a solution. Use this:

```
if(url.startsWith("https://www.google"){
//block site
}
```

Not smart but remains a way to effectively manage url